# How to create or set number of partitions for a topic?

Tags: python-3.x, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, kafka-producer-api

I'm using `python 3.6.8` and `kafka-python=2.0.2`

Is there a way to set the number of partitions for a topic from python code ?

My producer code looks:

```
producer = KafkaProducer(bootstrap_servers=['localhost:9092'],
                             value_serializer=lambda x:
                             dumps(x).encode('utf-8'))

producer.send("RANDOM_NEW_TOPIC", value={'test'})
```

I checked the manuals but can't see how can I update the number of partitions for a topic

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We could use Kafka Admin [CreatePartitions](https://kafka-python.readthedocs.io/en/master/apidoc/KafkaAdminClient.html#kafka.KafkaAdminClient.create_partitions) API to increase the number of partitions. The below show how to increase the partitions number to `4` for topic `topic1`

```
from kafka import KafkaAdminClient
from kafka.admin.new_partitions import NewPartitions

client = KafkaAdminClient(bootstrap_servers='localhost:9092')

rsp = client.create_partitions({
    'topic1': NewPartitions(4)
})
print(rsp)
```